# How to interpret "彼女が複数人いるような男"

Tags: relative-clauses, reading-comprehension

> ああもう、マジで彼女が複数人いるような男は普段から何してんだ。

speaker's thoughts on his futility on getting a date

> ...what do guys with lots of girls normally do?

not quite sure how to read 彼女が複数人いるような男, literally a guy that is similar to many girls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means:

> the kind of guy who has many girlfriends

AようなB means "a B that is like A," which in English we could also translate as "an A kind of B."

Recall also that いる, like ある can mean "to have". 彼女がいる = I have a girlfriend.